# Force on electric charge

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

What would the force on an electric charge in some ponderable media be, if the electric field due to the charge is not negligible compared to some external electric and magnetic field. I feel like it should be the Lorentz force with the macroscopic average fields $\textbf E$ and $\textbf B$, however, I have also come across a force law, the Einstein Laub force, which is different and depends on $\textbf H$ instead of $\textbf B$, and seems to apply in that situation instead of the Lorentz force. I don't see which one is correct. Is there a general way to calculate the contribution of the charges own field to the average electric field to include that appears in the expression for the force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no general formula for force in material medium, because there are many different kinds of medium with different behaviours.

In case the charged body is macroscopic, there is a simple formula for force on it due to other charged bodies: the Coulomb law formula, but the effective charges there are smaller than the actual charges due to liquid acting as a partial screen.

In case the dielectric is solid, no such simple formula exists, because solids can maintain stresses and these contribute to total force. You can read a little about this in Feynman, https://feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html sec. 10-5.

If you are after microscopic force in material medium, there is no simple formula in terms of macroscopic fields either, because when the particle is in the medium, it is acted upon by microscopic EM fields that are very intense and fluctuate on very small spatial and temporal scales due to other charges in close proximity.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. If we know the polarization and magnetization in general as a function of the E and B fields, would it then be possible to write a formula for the electromagnetic force for that medium, assuming that relation does not change? I would think the answer is then yes.

Comment: My answer says above says no, this is not possible. Force on a microscopic charged particle is highly position-dependent function due to close proximity of other charged particles. Force on macroscopic charged body, i.e. charged sphere, depends on whether the medium is liquid or solid and how the stress in the solid is distributed. These details are not accounted for by polarization or magnetization.

Comment: It is possible to express internal stressess in a piece of medium due to charges and rest of the medium in special cases, such as dielectric slab in capacitor with position-dependent dielectric constant.

Comment: See Panofsky, Phillips, *Classical electricity and magnetism*, section 6-6. The volume force on an element of dielectric depends on things such as gradient of dielectric constant.